# Bind global variable but no 'this' to a callback function

Tags: javascript

Here is an example. I know it doesn't work because bind() just bind the arguments of a function.

```
global_var = 2
var foo = function(){
  console.log(global_var)
}
var bar = foo.bind(null,/* global_var =*/ 3)
setTimeout(bar)
```

In my case, foo is from a library so it cannot be modified (not understand why it use global scope), that's why I cannot bind a scope "this" to the function.

bar is going to be a callback, and I want to make sure that it can output '3' every time.

Comment: I think mentioning which library, which function and what you are trying to do will be better. This isolation with example looks meaningless to me.

Comment: @sabithpocker Sorry I cannot mention the library. But I think my question make sense because it is all language level trick.

Comment: Im sorry, but this looks like a typical [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I do appreciate the edit you did, looks better.

Comment: It's not possible without assigning a new value to `global_var` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend your global function. Check the below code snippet.

Hope this helps you!

```js
var global = 2;
//your global library variable
var foo = function() {
  console.log('inside foo library');
};

//make the global function extended 
foo = (function(oldFn) {
  function newFoo() {
    oldFn();
    console.log('inside extended function')
    return 3;
  }
  return newFoo;
})(foo);

//callback variable
var bar = foo;

console.log(bar());
```